# Using the TelemetryClient in Applicationinsightss works only when the client is instantiated in a TelemetryConfiguration`s using statement

Tags: events, sdk, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I am working with ApplicationInsights, defining and sending my own custom events.

I use the telemetryclient for that.
It works only if I instantiate and use my telemetryclient object as following:

```
TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
using (var telemetryConfiguration = new TelemetryConfiguration("instrumentationKey"))
{
    telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);

    telemetryClient.TrackEvent("CustomEvent1");

    telemetryClient.Flush();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

The problem is, that I want to inject the telemtryClient in different services. Yet calling this call at the same Position generates no Events in the portal:

```
TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
using (var telemetryConfiguration = new TelemetryConfiguration("instrumentationKey"))
{
    telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);

}


telemetryClient.TrackEvent("CustomEvent1");

telemetryClient.Flush();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Is that the wrong way to use the telemtryClient?

Comment: Note for other developers who are fighting to use TelemetryClient  without injektion: the `using (telemetryConfiguration)` implies that our TelemetryConfiguration gets disposed right away and when it's time to log the configuration is not there anymore --> _AI: Process was called on the TelemetrySink after it was disposed, the telemetry data was dropped._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing a .Net Core Application you can configure dependency Injection of the TelemetryClient in the ConfigureServices method of your Startup.cs.
See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core) for a complete example.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        ...
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        ...
}
```

Then, if you are writing a Mvc app, for example, you can inject the TelemetryClient in your controllers like this:

```
private readonly TelemetryClient tc;

public MyController(TelemetryClient _tc)
{
    tc = _tc;
} 

public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    tc.TrackEvent("CustomEvent1");
    ...
}
```

Make sure to also configure your appsettings.json correctly:

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
"InstrumentationKey": "..." }
```

Hope this helps,
Andreas